# Is there a Confluence macro for last modified separated Page Sections, paragraphs and elements?

Tags: confluence

Recently we had the following problem:

The article includes several sections which are very important for my colleagues from three different departments.

According to my colleagues - the article is updated properly, except for one vital section which hasn't been updated for more that three months.

Default 'last modified' page block displays that the most recent update took place two weeks ago and our new colleagues had no idea about the section which hasn't been touched by the author for more than three months, which caused some issues.

Is there a way to create a macro which displays the most recent update for the selected section of the page? For example:

- **entire page** - last modified on Jun 06, 2019;
- **selected section** - last modified on Apr 03, 2019.

We need to use similar functionality like [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Include-last-modified-date-and-user-in-Page-Properties-Report/qaq-p/18371) and [also here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/Is-there-a-Macro-to-display-Last-Update-Date-of-the-Page/qaq-p/588873) , but the macro body should be able to select a section of the page (a paragraph or a table for example).

Confluence/Server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not possible (not the easy way you would like to have it implemented).

Except some heavy scripting ([ScriptRunner for Confluence](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1215215/scriptrunner-for-confluence?hosting=server&tab=overview)) or custom addon development, the only easy way is the following:

- Try to move these 3 sections into 3 separate sub-pages and link them the main (parent) page - using **Page Include** macro.
- On top of each section you may add information (custom macro) about last subpage updated date.

However, this solution has its pros & cons:

- (+) out of the box solution
- (+) you can further restrict pages who can and cannot edit the subpages (sections)
- (-) you need to script custom user macro to display the last page update of different page than current (should be easy)
- (-) teams will have to edit subpages instead of the main page (a simple process change)

Alternatively, you can check with StiltSoft and their [InPlace Editor](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/33286/inplace-editor-for-confluence?hosting=server&tab=overview) - this addon works with section and it would be interesting to let them ask if they are open to implement your requested functionality.